# Has anybody figured out how to add videos to a node gallery?

Tags: nodes, files, media

I've just finished building a node gallery image gallery system in drupal that lets my users add lots of photos easily to the site, and create their own galleries. However, I'd like them also be able to add video files. Node gallery says this is not available "out of the box" but possible, but I cant find any instructions on how to do this. I'm hoping someone out there has figured this out.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/video    This maybe is the module you need to try?

or users add simple link to youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LF30SUwr5Q